# How to pass C# method as a callback to CLI/C++ function?

Tags: c#, callback, c++-cli

I have such method in C++/CLI:

```
void Foo(OnEngineCloseCallback callback);
```

with such callback definition:

```
typedef void (*OnEngineCloseCallback)( int, String ^ errorMessage);
```

The C++/CLI compiles. The C# code looks like this:

```
static void onCallback( int code, String errorMessage)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(errorMessage);
}
```

and the call:

```
Foo(onCallback); // error
```

"Foo is not supported by the language" (error: CS0570).

So how can I pass my callback to CLI/C++?

Comment: You must declare a public delegate, not a function pointer.  Basic how-to article [is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c320cx3h.aspx).

Comment: The .NET version of a function pointer is a delegate; that's what C# can use.  It has no idea what a function pointer is.  You'll have to change the C++/CLI code to accept a delegate.

Comment: @HansPassant, could you please post regular answer, and not a comment -- in SO I cannot accept comment (technically).

Comment: @HansPassant, you didn't understand me -- your comment solved my problem, so please post your comment **AS** answer (not changing anything at all).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*If neither of you is going to post an answer I'll do it because I don't like answered questions without answers...*

> You must declare a public delegate, not a function pointer. Basic how-to article is here.
>   by Hans Passant

[How to: Define and Use Delegates (C++/CLI)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c320cx3h.aspx)